# How to disable spell checking in Firefox for a specific website/domain?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

I want spell checking enabled on Firefox except in a few websites.

How can I *permanently* disable spell checking in a specific website or a domain, e.g. `foo.xxx`?

I know I can right-click and remove the check mark from "Check Spelling" but that is temporary, I want something that saves the setting for that particular website or text field.

Answer (score 3):

Half solution but better than nothing:

You can turn off the default spell checking in Firefox ( `layout.spellcheckDefault` set to `0` ) and then use the https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/languagetool/ extension. [(recommended by Firefox)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recommended-extensions-program)

- Now you can get permanent domain exclusion in this extension:

[image]

- or that way:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's a website you have control over, you could set the `spellcheck` attribute on the `input` tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" />
```

I just used this attribute on a text field where I asked the user to enter a work order number that included letters and numbers.  (Definitely not a dictionary word.)  Worked perfectly.

Comment: I suppose if you don't have control over the website, you could use a Greasemonkey script to set the attribute, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: I don't control the website, this is for generic use across the web. I want spellchecking disabled for sites such as this one (`superuser.com`).